# how to get location based on multiple conditions in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How can I get my desired output based on two tables in sql server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Goal](
    [Location] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Goal] [int] NULL,
    [Month] [date] NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Master](
    [Date] [date] NULL,
    [Employee] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [GP] [int] NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](50) NULL
)
INSERT [dbo].[Goal] ([Location], [Goal], [Month]) VALUES (N'MG Road', 50000, CAST(0xB93D0B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Goal] ([Location], [Goal], [Month]) VALUES (N'Madiwala', 60000, CAST(0xB93D0B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Goal] ([Location], [Goal], [Month]) VALUES (N'Silk Board', 30000, CAST(0xB93D0B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Goal] ([Location], [Goal], [Month]) VALUES (N'BTM', 35000, CAST(0xB93D0B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Goal] ([Location], [Goal], [Month]) VALUES (N'MG Road', 55000, CAST(0xBA3D0B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Goal] ([Location], [Goal], [Month]) VALUES (N'Madiwala', 65000, CAST(0xBA3D0B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Goal] ([Location], [Goal], [Month]) VALUES (N'Silk Board', 35000, CAST(0xBA3D0B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Goal] ([Location], [Goal], [Month]) VALUES (N'BTM', 35000, CAST(0xBA3D0B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x283E0B00 AS Date), N'Ram', 2000, N'MG Road')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x283E0B00 AS Date), N'Ram', 1800, N'Silk Board')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x293E0B00 AS Date), N'Sami', 15000, N'BTM')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x2A3E0B00 AS Date), N'Ram', 2500, N'Silk Board')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x2A3E0B00 AS Date), N'Ram', 2500, N'MG Road')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x293E0B00 AS Date), N'Sami', 2000, N'BTM')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x2A3E0B00 AS Date), N'Sami', 19000, N'Madiwala')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x2E3E0B00 AS Date), N'Ram', 30000, N'MG Road')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x2E3E0B00 AS Date), N'Ram', 30000, N'Madiwala')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x2F3E0B00 AS Date), N'Ram', 25000, N'Madiwala')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x2E3E0B00 AS Date), N'Sami', 20000, N'BTM')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x2E3E0B00 AS Date), N'Sami', 15000, N'Silk Board')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master] ([Date], [Employee], [GP], [Location]) VALUES (CAST(0x2F3E0B00 AS Date), N'Sami', 15000, N'Silk Board')
```

based on above data I want output like below :

```
Employe |Location   |TotalGP|Month Goal |Goal %
Ram |MG Road    |3800   |50000          |7.6
Ram |MG Road    |5000   |50000          |10
Ram |Madiwala   |60000  |65000          |92.30769231
Sami    |Madiwala   |17000  |60000          |28.33333333
Sami    |Madiwala   |19000  |60000          |31.66666667
Sami    |Silk board |35000  |35000          |100
sami    |Silk board |15000  |35000          |42.85714286
Ram |Madiwala   |25000  |65000          |38.46153846
```

I tried this:

```
select employee,date,sum(gp)totalgp 
from master 
group by  employee,date 



select * from 
(select date,employee,location,gp,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by employee,date order by gp desc ) as rn 
from master 
) a
where rn=1
```

above query not given expected result.

Goal %: totalgp/monthgoal * 100

Month Goal:Month goal should be selected from the month goal table, and it should displaying the goal of the location in which the employee has yielded maximum GP (sum of GP) in a 
eg : Ram worked in both MG Road and madiwala, but his sum of GP is more in MG Road so MG road'Goal is diplayed against Ram for April month , but for May month Ram's Goal

Total GP definition:

Eg Ram  on 25-04-18 has gained 2000 only in MG road , but in other location on same day he has gained 1800 extra , so we are displaying 3800 for Ram irrespective to the location

Location column definition

Location - The employee might work in one or two locations , but here you should display the location in which he has scored maximum Gp (total Gp of the month in a 
eg : Ram worked in both MG Road and madiwala, but his sum of GP is more in MG Road so MG road is diplayed for April month , but for May month Ram locaion is madiwala

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
select date,employee,sum(gp)as totalgp,max(goal) as monthgoal,cast(sum(gp)* 100.0/max(goal) as float) as 'Goal%'
from goal 
inner join master on master.location=goal.location 
where month(goal.month)=month(master.date)
group by date,employee
```

The output is like this

```
date       employee                                           totalgp     monthgoal   Goal%
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------
2018-04-25 Ram                                                3800        50000       7.6
2018-04-26 Sami                                               17000       35000       48.571428571428
2018-04-27 Ram                                                5000        50000       10
2018-04-27 Sami                                               19000       60000       31.666666666666
2018-05-01 Ram                                                60000       65000       92.307692307692
2018-05-01 Sami                                               35000       35000       100
2018-05-02 Ram                                                25000       65000       38.461538461538
2018-05-02 Sami                                               15000       35000       42.857142857142
```

Note : 
You have to make the date format same for both the tables